# scipy RegularGridInterpolator The points in dimension 0 must be strictly ascending

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

When calling:

```
interpolator = scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator((X, Y, Z), data, method='linear')
```

I get the error "The points in dimension 0 must be strictly ascending".

Why must the points have strictly ascending x values?  Surely I can create an interpolator with data with the same x values at time, for example with the coordinates into the data array of

0,0,0 and 0,0,1

(or X = [0,0], y = [0,0] and Z = [0,1]

I must be missing something about the input format, but can't see what.

Comment: At a guess: one dimension must have an increasing array of values, and the first dimension was picked. Try with "rolled" axes to move your example Z dimension into X position.

Comment: the Z *really* isn't going to be strictly ascending though.  Surely I must be able to intepolate from all the values of an array,in which case no axis would be strictly ascending.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it looks like RegularGridInterpolator isn't what I need, because it requires all values in the grid to be defined.  LinearNDInterpolator is what I need.