# Filling in all elements of a sparse array by using interpolation

Tags: python, scipy

I have a sparse 3-dimensional numpy array of numbers, and I would like to fill in the "empty" spaces.

I can use scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator to do this, but I would prefer to actually interpolate.

scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator does not appear to be appropriate - it requires a non-sparse array.

Does anyone know of an appropriate method?

Comment: What's wrong with `LinearNDInterpolator`?  You have unstructured n-dimensional data.  It may be a subset of points on a regular grid, but it is still unstructured.  It is not `scipy.sparse` (which is restricted to 2d matrices).

Comment: I think LinearNDInterpolator needs there to be a convex hull of actual data around every non datapoint, or something.  This error I received showed that you can't just have a few points with data and fill out the rest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474656/scipy-regulargridinterpolator-the-points-in-dimension-0-must-be-strictly-ascendi